# How do I get the titles to print using Selenium's "find_elements_by_xpath"

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping

I'm writing an automation code to scrape independent insurance agent names, addresses, and zip codes from a website. I can't seem to identify the right xpath or write the right set of code to get the elements I want to print. I'm at the very beginnings of the process, and I'm just working to print out the Agency Names right now before I move on to the addresses and zip codes of the agents.

I've tried identifying and printing the data using both css selectors and xpaths. The website runs on Javascript so when I tried coding on Anaconda and using Scrapy, the spiders only scraped the html of the loading page and not the list of agents that showed up after, so I moved on to using Selenium with PyCharm. I've tried typing out the xpath a ton of different ways, but I get mostly the same results or same error messages.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchAttributeException
from selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement import WebElement

# My Chrome webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Users/Owner/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")

# The website I'm scraping is here 
url = "https://insurance-agent.safeco.com/find-an-insurance- 
agency/app/search-results-locationSearch=Chicago,%2520IL"
driver.get(url)

# The wait so the results page gets scraped and not the loading page
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

# Identifying the xpath of the agent name
Agency_Name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//[@id="srpgLftAgencyName"]')
print(Agency_Name)
```

I get outputs with a huge list of these:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="38691bf8d9c3c1c0ec8d3455899cb06f", element="0.2587047071773503-1")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="38691bf8d9c3c1c0ec8d3455899cb06f", element="0.2587047071773503-2")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="38691bf8d9c3c1c0ec8d3455899cb06f", element="0.2587047071773503-3")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="38691bf8d9c3c1c0ec8d3455899cb06f", element="0.2587047071773503-4")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="38691bf8d9c3c1c0ec8d3455899cb06f", element="0.2587047071773503-5")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="38691bf8d9c3c1c0ec8d3455899cb06f", element="0.2587047071773503-6")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="38691bf8d9c3c1c0ec8d3455899cb06f", element="0.2587047071773503-7")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="38691bf8d9c3c1c0ec8d3455899cb06f", element="0.2587047071773503-8")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="38691bf8d9c3c1c0ec8d3455899cb06f", element="0.2587047071773503-9")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="38691bf8d9c3c1c0ec8d3455899cb06f", element="0.2587047071773503-10")>]
```

What I'm trying to get is just plain text of the agency's names so I can export it to an excel doc.

(Here's the exact element in the html that I'm going for:

```
<a id="srpgLftAgencyName" class="agencyTitle ng-binding" ng- 
show="x.agencyPrimaryName != ' '" ng-href="/find-an-insurance- 
agency/app/agency/2428293524282935" href="/find-an-insurance- 
agency/app/agency/2428293524282935">
                    PJ NUNZIO AND ASSOCIATES, INC.
                </a>
```

Thanks!)

Answer (score 0):

Use [get_attribute or text](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html) method:

```
[agency.text for agency in Agency_Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

`find_elements_by_xpath`() will returns list NOT the `WebElement` so if you want to get element text you can use following options.

**Option 1:**

```
#use index this will returns first match
Agency_Name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//[@id="srpgLftAgencyName"]')[0]
print(Agency_Name.text)
```

**Option 2:**

```
#Use find_element this will return element 

Agency_Name = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//[@id="srpgLftAgencyName"]')
print(Agency_Name.text)
```